# How does semantics of Selenium DOM locators work?

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium

I'm trying to understand the semantics of Selenium DOM locators. The documentation states that they are basically Javascript expressions evaluated to get the target element. But if I try to evaluate eg `document.div[0].button[2]` (from [these examples](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html#_dom)), I just get `Error: TypeError: document.div is undefined`.

Is that example invalid? Is this an outdated way of navigating the DOM that's no longer supported in modern browsers but emulated by Selenium for backward-compatibility? Is there any documentation on how this syntax is meant to work?

Note that I'm not trying to *use* DOM locators - I'm well aware that using CSS or id or even XPath is cleaner. I, however, need to understand their semantics so I can write code that can convert common DOM locators into XPath locators for use in WebDriver.

Comment: There is a great overview of some DOM commands in Selenium here: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/ ... it talks a lot about the other selectors as well, but it may be useful in seeing what the commands look like. It gives a PDF file of basically what eugene has talked about below.

Comment: @Arran: This is actually pretty much what I was looking for. Using that table, I can write the converter I need. Could you put your comment up as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great overview of some DOM commands in Selenium here:

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

It talks a lot about the other selectors as well, but it may be useful in seeing what the commands look like, compared to it's alternatives. It gives a PDF file of basically what eugene has talked about above too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd share my understanding of DOM locators. There are several DOM abbreviations:

```
gEBI - getElementById
gEBTN - getElementsByTagName
```

Xpath locators and css selectors are used in the context of selenium web driver, and DOM locators are used in the context of javascript (i.e.  to locate element with DOM locator properly you shoulda wrap DOM locators with `JavascriptExecutor` firstly)

**usage example:**

```
Whole web page         document.documentElement
Whole web page body    document.body
Element <E> by absolute reference     document.body.childNodes[i]...childNodes[j]
Element <E> by relative reference     document.gEBTN('E')[0]   

document.getElementById('TestTable')
First <E> child     document.getEBTN('E')[0]
Last <E> child      document.gEBTN(E)[document.gEBTN(E).length-1]   

Second <E> child              document.getEBTN('E')[1]
Second-to-last <E> child      document.gEBTN(E)[document.gEBTN(E).length-2]
Parent of element <E>         document.gEBTN('E')[0].parentNode   

Descendant <E> of element with id I using specific path   
document.gEBI('I')…gEBTN('E')[0]      

Descendant <E> of element with id I using unspecified path
document.gEBI('I').gEBTN('E')[0]
```

So if you like to get this work we should call jsExecutor. It be somthing like:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "return document.getElementById('example');";
WebElement exampleDiv = (WebElement) js.executeScript(script);
exampleDiv.getText();
```

Also concerning your issue I've found a piece of explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129355/element-locator-use-in-selenium-xpath-css-dom)

Hope it be a lil bit more clear now)